# Интеграция html страницы в wordpress с возможностью частичного редактирования

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, шаблоны

Конкретный вопрос по WordPress. Имеется HTML-страница с несколькими css и js файлами, которую необходимо интегрировать в WordPress так, чтобы контент частично можно было редактировать: текст, ссылки, изображения. Для этой цели было решено подключить плагин Advanced Custom Fields и поместить контент HTML-страницы в отдельную страницу темы, чтобы навесить на нее через ACF группу полей с php-тегами, заменяющими ее статичный контент. Все бы ничего, но есть проблема с динамичностью: на эту странцу уже не работает плагин попапов, который затрагивает все имеющиеся страницы, кроме этой. Внимание, вопрос. Учитывая, что для ACF нужна отдельная страница, по-другому он, видимо не умеет, как можно наделить страницу динамичностью, например, чтобы другие плагины могли распространять на нее свой функционал? Опытным путем было найдено кривое решение с помощью вставки php-функций wp_head() и wp_footer() в эту страницу, она становится видимой для других плагинов, но вместе с этим в ней подгружаются родные стили темы, что портит стиль страницы, да так, что переопределить каскадность с помощью css становится просто мучением, да и неправильно это. Привязка к какой-либо теме не требуется, посколько интегрируемая страница в единственном экземпляре, а любые новые страницы планируется создавать в плагинах-конструкторах.
Благодарю за ваши советы.

Comment: Попробуй `wp_dequeue_style(...)` она как раз убирает подключенные ранее стили

Comment: Отличная, идея, спасибо! Дописываю в имеющей функции в functions.php дочерней темы строку wp_dequeue_style: `function child_enqueue_styles() {      if ( is_front_page() ){        wp_dequeue_style( 'astra-theme-css-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/minified/style.min.css', array());   } }  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_enqueue_styles', 15 );` Где косячу?

Comment: Все получилось, был лишний префикс -css. Еще раз благодарю.